# jQuery last-child Undefined Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have an issue getting the ID of my last-child with jQuery.

Here is my code with issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2ePeP/

My HTML code

```
<div>
    <p class="category" id="category_1">Appetizer</p>
    <p class="category" id="category_2">Beaverages</p>
    <p class="category" id="category_3">Dessert</p>
    <button type="button" class="add-category">Add</button>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
$('.add-category').click(function() {
    alert($('.category:last-child').attr('id'));
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:last` or `.last()`

```
$('.category:last');
```

or

```
$('.category').last()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ePeP/1/)

Comment: What a great simple solution that solves my headache. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please also be aware of [`:last` **Additional Notes**](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) section on non-(CSS)-standard selectors.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, I was stumped for hours and `$('.category:last');` totally worked!!!!! For some reason it was not liking `last()`

Answer (score 0):

`.last-child` will only try to match the very last child of a parent element - see MDN [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child), but the `<button>` is the last child in the parent `<div>`. There is no element with `class="category"` that is also a last child.

CSS does provide a selector that will work, which matches

> the last occurrence of a specified element, even if it doesn't come dead last in the HTML.

(from CSS Tricks [`:last-child`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/))

So the following will log the `id` of the last `class="category"` element.

```
$('.add-category').click(function() {
    console.log($('.category:last-of-type')[0].id);
});
```